# How to deploy Ionic app for remote internal users to test

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have an ionic app build on my system. 
For now, I have been testing my app using Ionic DevAPP (which can be found on the App Store and Google Play).

Prerequisite to run an app on my mobile device using Ionic DevApp is, My app needs to be up and running using the command:

```
ionic serve
```

This option looks great when doing development.

But now, I have my app build and I want to share it with the testing team and PO who is located on shore.

I want to know is there any way or free platform where the users can run an app on their mobile devices directly without starting a dev server.

**NOTES**:

1. I know about Ionic dashboard, but it is not free when comes to sharing builds.
2. I don't want to upload my app on Play Store or Google Play.

Any help is recommended as I am really looking for options to share my app.

Comment: you can make APK. `ionic build android` this will generate your debug APK and you can share it with your testers. 
`ionic run android` to build apk directly on device.

Comment: @Najamussaqib Yes! But what about IOS build?

Comment: For IOS you should have MAC available with xcode installed. your can build iOS build with it. 
`cordova build ios` this will generates your xcode project. open it with xcode and build it on device.

Comment: okay. Look's like an option where I can generate APK and IPA files and share with the team. But looking for more suggestions as well.

Comment: you can share it via https://www.diawi.com/ . upload your IPA or APK and share it with your testes or anyone you want. But in ios build it will required device ID you install.

Comment: Have you looked into Google Play Console's ability to manage test builds?  You'll need to use that tool to deploy anyway - might as well get familiar.  For iOS, have you looked at Test Flight? https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: Thanks, @BRass. Let me check them.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Diawi](https://diawi.com) To share both apk and ipa, bypassing play/app stores.